# How to create a 4-channel audio file out of 4 separate audio files in R?

Tags: r, audio

I am very much a beginner to R. I am writing to this forum because I have often found very useful questions and answers in here. I am trying to create a 4-channel .wav audio file out of the right channel of 4 separate stereo audio files. This is what I have tried to do using tuneR:

```
# read in 4 stereo audio files

s1A <- readWave("/090306_1A.wav")
s2A <- readWave("/090306_2A.wav")
s3A <- readWave("/090306_3A.wav")
s4A <- readWave("/090306_4A.wav")

# extract the right channel as a vector file

m1A <- s1A@right
m2A <- s2A@right
m3A <- s3A@right
m4A <- s4A@right

# combine the four files into one multi-channel file

A_1 <- WaveMC(data = list(m1A, m2A, m3A, m4A), samp.rate = 96000, bit = 16, pcm = TRUE)

# write the multi-channel file as a .wav file

writeWave(A_1, filename = "/A_1.wav", extensible= TRUE)
```

Here I get an error message saying :

```
"Error in writeWave(A_1, filename = "/A_1.wav",  : 
  colnames(object) must be specified and must uniquely identify the channel ordering for WaveMC objects, see ?MCnames for possible channels"
```

I have looked at MCnames and can see that a data frame with three variables (id, label and name for all the 4 channels) is necessary. What I can not find is how to create it correctly (meaning what should id, label and name be?) and how to use it with writeWave? I have checked the website referred to in the R help files under MCnames but I still can not understand how to use it in my case.  I have tried all sorts of combinations - here is one:

```
id = c("m1A","m2A","m3A","m4A")
label = c("Front Left - FL", "Front Right - FR", "Front Center - FC", "Low Frequency - LF")
name = c(1,2,3,4)
names <- data.frame(id, label, name)
writeWave(A_1, colnames(names), filename = "/A_1.wav", extensible= TRUE)
```

This results also in an error message:

```
"Error in writeWave(A_1, colnames(names), filename = "/A_1.wav",  : 
  unused argument (colnames(names))
```

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance,
Outi

Comment: It may be better for you to directly send a message to the package author.

Comment: Thanks. I have done that now and hope to hear back from him.

Comment: I went through the CRAN manual and saw that you can have list and data frame in `WavMac()` Given you have four channels, list may be right. But I wonder if the function is expecting a data frame. I am just speculating. Hope you hear from the author soon.

Comment: I heard back from the author and he was very helpful. List is fine as long as the channels have a name. This is the way to give a name to the channels: colnames(A_1) <- c("FL", "FR", "FC", "LF")

Comment: My new problem now is that evenif I specify the format of the .wav file to be pcm=TRUE in WaveMC, my sound analysing programs (Raven Pro and Ishmael) don´t recognise the file as a pcm wave file and can´t therefore open it. Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: I am not familiar with tuneR, but have you checked sampling rate, for example?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really test if it works, but you should do the naming in A_1
try the following code:

```
colnames(A_1$Data) <- c("Front Left - FL", "Front Right - FR", "Front Center - FC", "Low Frequency - LF")
```

and then run the final line.

Comment: Hi Yevgeny, I tried your line but got unfortunately an error message saying : Error in `*tmp*`$Data : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks in advance, Outi